# Why can't audio.play () be executed, I looked in inspect element and saw some sort of Uncaught error (in promise) DOMexception

Tags: javascript, html, css, audio

I'm getting the error message!

```js
let fillbar=document.querySelector('.fill');
var audios= ["HOTEL_LOBBY.mp3", "FROZEN.mp3", "DOUBLE_UP.mp3"];
let covers=["popsmoke.jpg","2scratch.jpg","ian.jpg"];
let currentTime=document.querySelector(".time");

//Create an Object of Audio

let audio = new Audio();
let currentSong = 0;

// whenever the window load, the song should play automatically

window.onload = playSong;

// let's play the song by this function whenever window load

function playSong() {
  audio.src = audios[currentSong];
  audio.play();
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wqt1e.png)

I also checked other questions that arose related to this problem but nothing works for me or at least I think so. I am at the beginning and it is very difficult for me to figure out what I need to do to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The user must interact with the DOM first for the audio to play. Perhaps you can autoclick some hidden element?

```js
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<hidden style="display: none;"></hidden>');
document.querySelector('hidden').click();
// play audio
```

Comment: Not work `function playSong() {
  audio.src = audios[currentSong];
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('<hidden style="display: none;"></hidden>');
  document.querySelector('hidden').click();
  audio.play();
}`

Comment: sorry but i dont understand what to do

Comment: I forgot to make sure that insertAdjacentHTML had two arguments, so replace your current code with the new one.

Comment: in internet explore my code work and song started idk why I cant play in chrome ore opera

Comment: because in chromium browsers there are more security measures. Did the new code work?

Comment: yes i add play button so my song start after press button and work